# Getting locations within radius using firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

```
Future<List<Places>> nearYou(GeoPoint point) async {
    final CollectionReference places = firestore.collection('places');
    // 10km radius around point (in lat and long)
    double radius = 0.01;

    final query = places
        .where('coordinates',
            isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: GeoPoint(
              point.latitude - radius,
              point.longitude - radius,
            ))
        .where('coordinates',
            isLessThanOrEqualTo: GeoPoint(
              point.latitude + radius,
              point.longitude + radius,
            ))
        .limit(5);
    var snapshot = await query.get();
    ...
```

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work. I don't even get the place nearest to my location.

Comment: How would a point on earth be "less or equal too" another point on earth?